# MATLAB code Output

Tags: c, matlab, math, matrix

In Matlab, what would be the output for the following,

v = [1 2 3 4]
b = [2 2 2 2]'

output of this calculation,
v + b

Comment: Why don't you try? If you don't have Matlab you can use [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), which is basically a freeware clone. But what does your head tell you? You're adding a row vector to a column vector (the ' means transpose) - does that make sense?

Comment: "Error using +: Matrix dimensions must agree"

Comment: This community is not here to run your own code for you. We are here to troubleshoot problems you may have with code, or to help you understand how to implement code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you get:

> > v = [ 1 2 3 4]

```
v =

 1     2     3     4
```

> > b = [2 2 2 2]'

```
b =

 2
 2
 2
 2
```

> > v + b

```
 Error using  + 
 Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe would be [3 4 5 6] unless the ' was purposeful, then nothing as you can't add the matrixs like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can't add a column vector and a row vector like that...

Perhaps you actually want to do

```
repmat(v,4,1)+repmat(b,1,4)
```

where  repmat(v,4,1) is

```
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
```

and repmat(b,1,4) is a 4x4 matrix with every element equal to 2.